# How to add Youtube video in Woocommerce product photo gallery?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I wordpress, I have created a custom textarea field to paste in Youtube Embed Code for every Products under Woocommerce. I used ACF plugin for that. The backend is working fine and I am able to fetch the video embed code using below code.

```
$video_embed_code = get_field('video_embed_code', $post->ID);
if($video_embed_code):
    echo '<div class="video-wrapper">'.$video_embed_code.'</div>';
endif;
```

This also works fine fetches video wherever needed. But I want to place it in the product gallery which is internally a combination of 3 plugins created by woocommerce
1. flexslider
2. photozoom
3. photoswipe

I want to add this video in this galley, so that it integrate finely with all the slides and when we click on zoom button, it loads the video using photoswipe plugin. I tried to look for woocommerce hooks but the only hook I found was to modify the flexslider settings like show/hide arrows, show/hide thumbnails etc.